# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date when typing the date in eclipse console

Tags: java, eclipse, date, time

I'm developing a code to convert the provided date time to GMT date time. When I'm providing the date time in the code according to the following snippet, it's working fine.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateInString = "22-01-2015 08:15:55 AM"; 
Date date_1 = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

But when I'm inputting the same date time as input on the console, console is displaying java.text.ParseException according to the following snippet.

```
System.out.println("Enter time in 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a' format");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String dateInString = sc.next();
Date date_1 = formatter.parse(dateInString);
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You should not use the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They're obsolete and troublesome. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead. In your case, `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Please don't post your error messages as screenshots.  Copy and paste the text into your question and format it appropriately using SO's markdown.

Comment: I too recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It seems that your format pattern string is not parsing the AM or PM part of the string. You need to do that to get the correct time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem.

```
String dateInString = sc.next();
```

The `next()` call returns the next white-space delimited token which is "22-01-2015"  rather than "22-01-2015 08:15:55 AM".

The parser says ... "Where is the time?   Bzzztt!"

Solution: use `nextLine()` to read a complete line of input.

---

(The clue is in the exception message.  It gives you back the string that you asked it to parse ...)

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of using sc.next()** use **nextLine()** method in the Scanner class,because **next() will only read upto the first space of your input**.So your input will take as 22-01-2015 instead of 22-01-2015 08:15:55 AM.

**Use sc.nextLine() method then the problem will be solved.**